# iOS How To Make Conference Call?

Tags: ios, phone-call, conferencing

I'm planning to create a call recording app. Is it possible to make a conference call from my app between user, calling number and VoIP service(witch will record the call)?

Comment: You can't combine a mobile call and a VoIP call. The user would need to conference in your service as a standard conference call or your VoIP service would need to handle all 3 legs and not use the mobile voice directly

Comment: Ok, and if I use standard call for recording, can I make a conference? Which method should I use? .openURL "tel://" or something else?

Comment: The user would need to initiate the conference.  You can't do it programatically

Comment: And what about incoming calls? Can I answer a call and make a conference after it?

Comment: No, the user would need to initiate the conference

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VoIP service, yes it is possible.
Using Multipeer Connectivity Framework's NSOutputStream and NSInputStream you will be able to transmit of audio.

Comment: But in this case I can't combine a mobile call and a VoIP call?

Comment: no you cannot combine a mobile call and a VoIP call. For that purpose you would be needing a hardware junction for the conversion process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!